# Use regex expression in gsub replacement map?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
def self.simultaneos_gsub(arguments)
  map_of_regex = Hash[arguments]
  re = Regexp.union(map_of_regex.keys)
  s = self.gsub(re, map_of_regex)
end
```

The arguments will be something like:

```
[[/[0-9]/i, '-'], [/@/, 'T']]
```

So `"019@hey"` should return `"---They"`.

A better example of what I want is:

```
arguments = [[/[a-z]/i, '@'], [/@/, '-']]

Input: 'This is just a @234' should return => '@@@ @@ @@@@ @ -234'
```

The `gsub` is finding the right characters but is replacing them with blank.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the hash version the keys have to be strings, not regular expressions, compare: `"foo".gsub(/o/, {'o' => 'a'}) #=> "faa"` and `"foo".gsub(/o/, {/o/ => 'a'}) #=> "f"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[18] pry(main)> s = "019@hey"
=> "019@hey"
[19] pry(main)> [[/[0-9]/i, '-'], [/@/, 'T']].each { |k,v| s.gsub!(k, v) }
=> [[/[0-9]/i, "-"], [/@/, "T"]]
[20] pry(main)> s
=> "---They"
```

the rewritten method, so args could either be an Hash e.g `{ /[0-9]/i => '-', /@/ => 'T' }` or an array containing an arrays with each having 2 elements e.g `[[/[0-9]/i, '-'], [/@/, 'T']]`

```
def simultaneous_gsub(string, args)
   st = string.dup
   args.each { |k,v| st = st.gsub(k, v) }
   st
end
```

Example usage:

```
string = "019@hey"
simultaneous_gsub(string, { /[0-9]/i => '-', /@/ => 'T' })
#=> "---They"
or
string = "019@hey"
simultaneous_gsub(string, [[/[0-9]/i, '-'], [/@/, 'T']])
#=> "---They"
```

Comment: @content01 the upper portion is from my pry session the lower portion is the actual method, and I have edited the answer to include example use

Comment: Yes but I'm trying to avoid the "each". I want it to be simultaneous

Comment: @content01 I doubt you can avoid using each and have a clean written code, alternative would be to pass a block to `gsub` but that would still look like the `each` version or worse

Comment: @muistooshort that's after a long day, the brain usually choose the safe option when it is tired, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the gsub done in a single line, then you can create a hash representing all the possible match characters mapped to their replacement character.  Documentation regarding providing a hash as an argument to `gsub` can be [found here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Here's code that could do it.  It's not pretty, but it seems like you're pretty intent on `gsub` being called just once.

Here's what I would do:

```
# Create a hash that looks like this...
# replacement_hash = { 
#   'a' => '@',
#   'b' => '@',
#   ...
#   'Z' => '@',
#   '@' => '-' }

replacement_hash = {}
(('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a).each { |char| replacement_hash[char] = '@' }
replacement_hash['@'] = '-'

'This is just a @234'.gsub(/[a-zA-Z\@]/, replacement_hash)  # => "@@@@ @@ @@@@ @ -234"
```

#### Caveats

To get this work within your function, you would need to provide a map of matched strings to their corresponding replacements.  Then, your regular expression would need to be an alternation (`|`) between all of those possible search strings.  It's a little easier to pull this off, as above, when it's just a single character replaced by a different character/symbol/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help 'splain things:

```
class String
  def simultaneos_gsub(arguments)
    map_of_regex = Hash[arguments]
    re = Regexp.union(map_of_regex.keys)  # => /0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|@/, /a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|@|T/
    self.gsub(re, map_of_regex)           # => "---They", "@@@@ @@ @@@@ @ -234"
  end
end

arguments = Hash[('0'..'9').zip(['-'] * 10)]
arguments['@'] = 'T'
arguments # => {"0"=>"-", "1"=>"-", "2"=>"-", "3"=>"-", "4"=>"-", "5"=>"-", "6"=>"-", "7"=>"-", "8"=>"-", "9"=>"-", "@"=>"T"}
"019@hey".simultaneos_gsub(arguments) # => "---They"

arguments = Hash[('a' .. 'z').zip(['@'] * 26)]
arguments.merge!({'@' => '-', 'T' => '@'})
# should return => '@@@ @@ @@@@ @ -234'
'This is just a @234'.simultaneos_gsub(arguments) # => "@@@@ @@ @@@@ @ -234"
```

The keys of the hash being passed to `gsub` are not regex patterns, they're the values that were matched in the string. The keys need to get turned into a pattern for the first parameter of `gsub`.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't married to `gsub`, you can do this with recursion, `split`, and `join`:

```
class String
  def simultaneos_gsub(arguments)
    if arguments.empty?
      self
    else
      argument = arguments.pop
      parts = split(argument.first)
      parts.collect! {|part| part.simultaneos_gsub(arguments) }
      parts.join(argument.last)
    end
  end
end

arguments = [[/[a-z]/i, "@"], [/@/, "-"]]
string = "This is just a @234"

string.simultaneos_gsub(arguments)
#=> "@@@@ @@ @@@@ @ -234"
```

This avoids the problem I assume you are trying to solve of `gsub`ing portions of the string you've already replaced multiple times by removing the parts of the string you are replacing and then adding them back in as the replaced value.